# WPF IsEnabled binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-4.5

I have trouble understanding how to disable textbox if value is different than 550. It is either disabled for all values if initial value is different from 550 or enabled for all values if initial value is equal to 550. The problem is it wont update when i change value in UI.

here is my xaml

```
<src:CustomTextBox VerticalAlignment = "Center"
                   Text="{Binding TrafoProperties.InsulationLevels.LightningImpulseVoltage,
                                  UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged,
                                  Mode = TwoWay,                    
                                  ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors = True,
                                  NotifyOnValidationError = True}"
                    Validation.ErrorTemplate = "{StaticResource defaultErrorTemplate}"
                   IsEnabled="{Binding Path = TrafoProperties.InsulationLevels.IsEnabled, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
```

And my two propeteries

```
public double LightningImpulseVoltage
{
    get { return _LightningImpulseVoltage; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _LightningImpulseVoltage, value);
        if (OnLightningImpulseVoltage != null)
            OnLightningImpulseVoltage();
    }
}

public bool IsEnabled 
{
    get { return LightningImpulseVoltage == 550; }
    set
    {
       OnPropertyChanged("LightningImpulseVoltage");
    }
}
```

My SetProperty

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
{
     if (object.Equals(storage, value)) 
        return false;

     storage = value;
     this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
     return true;
    }
```

And my OnPropertyChanged

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (eventHandler != null)
    {
        eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put a scrren shot that describe what you are doing

Comment: @HakamFostok basically i am picking values from drop box and values in textbox that meant to be disabled are changing

Comment: I don't see you ever raising `PropertyChanged` for "IsEnabled".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bound to `IsEnabled` which is dependent on `LightingImpulseVoltage`.  If you want that binding to update when the `LightingImpulseVoltage` value changes you will need to raise `PropertyChanged` in *that* property setter, like this:

```
public double LightningImpulseVoltage
{
    get { return _LightningImpulseVoltage; }
    set 
    { 
        SetProperty(ref _LightningImpulseVoltage, value);
        if (OnLightningImpulseVoltage != null)
            OnLightningImpulseVoltage();
        OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
    }
}
```